# Mysterious DropShadow in the Tab-Label. Scripture always has a shadow -shadow can not be removed

Tags: css, javafx, dropshadow

Hi Community,

I recently started to learn JavaFX. Now I wanted to create a navigation using the TabPane.

The surface is created via FXML and should be styled with CSS. As seen on the picture below, the whole thing should look like:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/162059/Foren_Bilder/Tabs.png

But atm it looks like this one:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/162059/Foren_Bilder/tabsfail.png

I'm not abled to remove this mysterious DropShadow. The shadow was placed at the AnchorPane Layer with the styleClass "shadow", but  this can not be override in the Childnodes  via -fx-effekt: null;.

Now I have already tried various things - without success.

The shadow remains stubbornly!

Maybe someone of you knows this "problem" and can tell me his proposed solution.

I am pleased with every tip.

Succession nor the FXML and the CSS file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="pane" fx:id="anchorpane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"   maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="589.0" prefWidth="1000.0" styleClass="shadow" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="viewController.TabModulController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../css/tabs.css" />
    </stylesheets>
<children>
<TabPane prefHeight="496.0" prefWidth="827.0" style="-fx-effect: null;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
      <content>
       <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
     </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

CSS:
    @CHARSET "UTF-8";

.shadow
    {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 5, 0.0, 0, -1);
    }

```
.noshadow
{
    -fx-effect: null;
}

.tab-pane
{
-fx-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
-fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tab-header-background
 {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
 }

.tab
 {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
 }

 .tab-label
 {
-fx-effect: null;
 }

 .tab:selected
 {
-fx-background-color: #fff;
-fx-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
-fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}


.headers-region
{
-fx-effect: null !important;
}

.tab-close-button
{ 
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: null
}
```

Comment: its about text-shadow , have you tried : -fx-text-shadow: 0 0 ; or -fx-effect: textshadow .... ;

Comment: I've tried it - no effect. the scenebuilder mean that no effects are set. Attribute "-fx-effect" shows the value "-"

Comment: so it has to be somewhere else. see if you can overwrite , reset, setting text-shadows effect to 0 0